# How can i access element value in SOAP response with lxml objectify

Tags: python, soap, lxml, objectify

I have SOAP response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:body><createsessionresponse soapenv:encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><createsessionreturn xsi:type="xsd:string">59C3F170141E9CF6F5BF98FB39B0237B</createsessionreturn></createsessionresponse></soapenv:body></soapenv:envelope>
```

objectify.dump returns this:

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope = None [ObjectifiedElement]
    {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body = None [ObjectifiedElement]
        createSessionResponse = None [ObjectifiedElement]
          * {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}encodingStyle = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
            createSessionReturn = '701C301EAA37A965B1B54A8EFD9ACD6F' [StringElement]
              * xsi:type = 'xsd:string'
```

How can i access the value of createSessionReturn ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createSessionResponse` is not using the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace

```
>>> import lxml.objectify
>>> doc = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:body><createsessionresponse soapenv:encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><createsessionreturn xsi:type="xsd:string">59C3F170141E9CF6F5BF98FB39B0237B</createsessionreturn></createsessionresponse></soapenv:body></soapenv:envelope>"""
>>> obj = lxml.objectify.fromstring(doc)
>>> obj
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}envelope at 0x2978eb0>
>>> for e in obj.iter():
...     print repr(e)
... 
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}envelope at 0x2978eb0>
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}body at 0x2978f50>
<Element createsessionresponse at 0x297c050>
'59C3F170141E9CF6F5BF98FB39B0237B'
>>>
```

[lxml.objectify documentation](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#namespace-handling) mentions:

> Lookups, however, inherit namespaces implicitly:

so `obj.body.createsessionresponse.createsessionreturn` won't work

```
>>> obj.body
<Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}body at 0x2978f00>
>>> obj.body.createsessionresponse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 218, in lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement.__getattr__ (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:3488)
  File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 437, in lxml.objectify._lookupChildOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:5743)
AttributeError: no such child: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}createsessionresponse
>>>
```

Still in the documentation

> To access an element in a different namespace than its parent, you can
>   use getattr():
>
> For convenience, there is also a quick way through
>   item access: `c = root["{http://other/}c"]`

Applied to your case it becomes:

```
>>> obj.body["{}createsessionresponse"]
<Element createsessionresponse at 0x2978f50>
>>> obj.body["{}createsessionresponse"].createsessionreturn
'59C3F170141E9CF6F5BF98FB39B0237B'
>>>
```

---

```
>>> obj.body["{}createsessionresponse"].createsessionreturn
'59C3F170141E9CF6F5BF98FB39B0237B'
>>> type(obj.body["{}createsessionresponse"].createsessionreturn)
<type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>
>>> obj.body["{}createsessionresponse"].createsessionreturn.text
'59C3F170141E9CF6F5BF98FB39B0237B'
>>> type(obj.body["{}createsessionresponse"].createsessionreturn.text)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Spent a whole evening.